# Bootstrap + React: navbar toggler not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

So, I have this stateless component, and I've been trying to integrate Bootstrap into my code. I did this in vanilla HTML/CSS and JS and it works fine. However, for some reason, the data-target="#navigation-bar" of my button when the screen is smaller than a certain width does not take the info from the class with the same id. Here is the component's code below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
const Navigation = (props) => {
const navNames = props.tabs.map(tab => {
    return <li className="nav-item" key={`${tab}`}><a className="nav-link" href={`${tab}`}>{tab}</a></li>
})
return (
  <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation-bar">
      <span className="navbar-toggler-icon">&#9776;</span>
  </button>
  <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigation-bar">
    <ul className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      {navNames}
    </ul>
  </div>
  </nav>
)
```

}

ultimately, I'm trying to make the navigation tabs (that come in as props) collapse into a single drop down button when it's a small screen to avoid pollution. :)

Answer (score 3):

So, React and vanilla Bootstrap don't really mix well. Bootstrap is supposed to alter DOM elements on DOM element changes. React has this concept of a virtual DOM to render the page based on what changed since previous render.

For React with Bootstrap, you can probably check libraries like https://react-bootstrap.github.io/, which are rebuilt to work with React.

Comment: Please consider marking this as the accepted answer if its an appropriate answer for what you asked